# Android TextView Wrap

Tags: java, android, android-activity, textview

Here is my problem. How to make text don't wrap?

I already tried to make text smaller. Didn't work. Tried to do `singleline="true"`. Here is  what he do(2 screen shot 6-7 textview)

1 Screenshot) Here is I made it in the Eclipse

2 Screenshot) Here is how it showen in the emulator

[image: Here is I made it in the Eclipse]
[image: Here is how it showen in the emulator]

Comment: there is no code... there is only OnCreate startActivity

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try setting `android:ellipsize` to `none` for each `TextView`. For more details see [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3aellipsize) on this attribute.

*From xml:*

```
<TextView ... android:ellipsize="none" />
```

*From code:*

```
 TextView textView = new TextView(context);
 ...
 textView.setEllipsize(null);
```

Answer (score 3):

try giving android:maxLines=1... singleLine property should also work...

Comment: no. For since it cuts the text, and doesn't show the rest.